# Android error : Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token) for background image

Tags: android, xml, background-image

i am new to android development

and when i am put image background than i am get this error :

### this is my code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Click_Page"
    android:background="@layout/img" >



</RelativeLayout>
```

---

Error Log :
error: Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)
img.png /AmcostApp/res/layout   line 1  Android AAPT Problem

---

please need solution

thanks in advance

Comment: images are kept in the drawable folder my dear friend. @drawable/img

Comment: thanks bro and sorry for my silly question.. :(

Comment: we are all stupid in the begining :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are setting background from layout. use drawable to set the images from the drawable folder as a background. eg:

```
android:background="@drawable/imageName"
```

Answer (score 3):

Make the following change: `android:background="@drawable/img"` and place your image in the `res/drawable` folder. If it doesn't exist, create it manually.